# MATLAB curve fit display equation on graph

Tags: matlab, curve-fitting

Is there a way to display the `curvefit` equation on the graph produced without having to write it down myself manually every time? By GUI or command-line, anything is okay. Any hacks, some way to get around this?

Comment: Please post some code as to how you obtain the fit for your curve.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably easiest to use the `fit` utility which is the non-graphical equivalent of using `curvefit`:

```
% sample data
x=[1:10]'; 
y = x+randn(10,1)*0.5; 
plot(x,y,'o')

pars=fit(x,y,'poly1');
```

`pars` contains the result of the fit, which you can overlay on the plot above with

```
hold on
plot(pars)
```

If you want to see the values of individual parameters, you can type `pars.p1` or `pars.p2` (for this example, there may be other parameters "pn" for other models)

To display on the figure, you can do something simple like

```
xpos=3;
ypos=9;
text(xpos,ypos,{num2str([pars.p1;pars.p2])})
```

For more info look into the documentation for [curvefit](http://www.mathworks.se/help/curvefit/) or try `help curvefit` or `help fit`.